# How to display image data from url in UICollectionView with different size?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

how to correctly display image data form url in `UICollectionViewCell`, it has a default image before loading image from url, after estimate image size and resized the image to proper size then display, is there any example or hint that I can refer?

and one more thing, should I subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` or `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` in this case? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass cell and override layoutSubviews method. This is an `UITableViewCell` [example](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2011/11/sdwebimage-fixed-width-cell-images/), but I think it's a good start for you.